# How does Python string comparison _really_ work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, internationalization

So, in Python, strings have an inherent ordering;

```
>>>'A' < 'B' < 'C'
True
>>>"angler" < "beta fish" < "coleocanth"
True
```

Most sources say strings in Python are ordered by ASCII code - except that's clearly nonsense, since Python 3 strings are Unicode.

Obviously there's a defined ordering for A, B, C... and presumably other languages have similar alphabetical orderings.

But how do you order, say, '♳', '▧' and 'ⵞ'? More to the point, how do you order Ａ, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , A, and Ⱥ?

I'd *assume* it falls back to comparing Unicode code points; that'd be simplest and seems like a reasonable default, but it'd also suggest that, for example, `¾' < '⅐' < '↉', and '⓿' > '⓵' > '⒌' > '⑽' > '⑮', and "Ａ" > "C" (that's a fullwidth A) which seems a little... un-Pythonic, even if it is a really weird edge case.

Is there a more intricate set of rules that are used, and if so, where are they documented? Is it implementation-defined or is there a standard?

Comment: "it'd also suggest that, for example, '¼' < '⅐' < '↉'" - that's not any more problematic than `"10" < "2"`.

Comment: Some languages have a more complex ordering than can be accommodated by a simple `<`, even English if you choose to ignore case.

Comment: It's Pythonic to compare lexicographically because Unicode collation is a huge can of worms that should be opened explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) (and frustratingly, not mentioned in the docs for the string type):

> Strings (instances of `str`) compare lexicographically using the numerical Unicode code points (the result of the built-in function `ord()`) of their characters.

This is normative, and accurate to the implementation. You can view the Python 3.6.3 implementation of string comparison [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11215).

Comment: Note: For locale aware string comparisons (that actually take into account the logical meaning of characters, at least to a certain extent), you can use [`locale.strxfrm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.strxfrm) as your sorting `key` function.